# How much does keeping beans vacuum sealed matter?

Tags: storage, beans

I use a moka pot (makineta) to make coffee, and I keep the beans in a bag (not sealed) in the freezer.

I keep getting people saying that in order to get to best aroma and the most fresh coffee the beans must be kept in vacuum after roasting until use, and due to this fact there is no escape but using the sealed Nespresso capsules and their machine (or any other capsule espresso machine equivalent).

How much does it matter? How much of the aroma/freshness is lost if the beans are not kept in vacuum? (but are being ground only prior to making a cup)

Answer (score 10):

Coffee beans are freshest from about 12 to 48 hours after roasting until maybe one or two weeks later when stored properly in an airtight container.  During the early portion of this period (immediately after roasting to three or four days later) beans will be still giving off some gases, thus the reason for one way valves on coffee bags.  That being the case, vaccuum sealing can extend that time some, but not indefinitely.  Storing your coffee in the freezer actually makes the problem worse since the freeze thaw cycle drys the beans out and forces the oils to separate out of the beans.

Comment: So if I buy the beans from a homemade roasting business and they come in a normal plastic bag, the best I can do would be to just keep them in the closet and avoid the freezer? I thought the freezer is the magic solution for all culinary freshness...

Comment: Correctish.  Storing them in the closet in an airtight container would be better (I use mason jars, personally).  The freezer is fine for long term storage (assuming you have vacuum sealed your item).  However, freezing, thawing and refreezing items repeatedly tends to ruin them quicker.